# Generate an array of integers from text file of strings on separate lines. Better way?

Tags: python, arrays, string, integer

So I have this extremely long .txt file that contains all **unordered** integers from 0 to 100,000, inclusive.

Ex of .txt

```
142142
142421
45454
355
etc...
```

And after some manipulation I was able to successfully achieve the goal of generating an array from those numbers into a list of strings.

```
arr = open('/Users/macroot/Desktop/data.txt')
data = []
for line in arr:
    data.append(line)
data

Out[ ]: ['142142\n',
         '142421\n',
         '45454\n',
         '355\n',
         'etc...\n']
```

Furthermore, I even figured out that I can remove the new line tag and convert each element to an integer.

```
data = list(map(lambda x: int(x.rstrip()), data))
data

Out[ ]: [142142,
         142421,
         45454,
         355,
         etc...]
```

Wonderful! Now I can put this into a merge sort algorithm and count some inversions! But wait, what is my question?

**Surely there is a better, built in method that reads in a file and does these modifications automatically, right?**

Comment: You could use [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)

Comment: *"contains all unordered integers from 0 to 100,000"* – Is that order relevant in any particular way? Because you could create a simple list of shuffled integers in that same range very easily without any file…

Comment: I would say that's a quite good way to do it. You could also do simply this line inside a `with open("file.txt", "r") as file:` statement: `[int(line.rstrip("\n")) for line in file.readlines()]`

Comment: `data.append(int(line.strip()))`

Comment: @deceze interesting that you said that. Yeah you could. But I was given that file with the expectation of there being a very specific number of inversions. As such, the order as provided is, indeed, important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Surely there is a better, built in method that reads in a file and
>   does these modifications automatically, right?

Since your file constains a lot of lines, it's a good idea to read the content line by line instead of whole content. But you can simplify this by using a *list comprehension*.

```
with open('/Users/macroot/Desktop/data.txt') as f:
     array = [int(line) for line in f]
```

Also, if you're using *numpy* library you can apply

```
array = np.genfromtxt('/Users/macroot/Desktop/data.txt', dtype=np.int32)
```

which returns a *generator*.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer. A two liner instead of the 5 liner I came up with and the 4 liner Avezan suggested. Cheers